# Moblie Flex application trace()

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, actionscript, trace

I'm working on a mobile flex application and I was wondering if there is a possibility to get the result of the trace function inside the application and not in the console to display it while running and without PC.

Comment: Very unclear question. Please provide more details and let us know what you have already tried?

Comment: Take the label and display result inside that. no need of trace.

Comment: Yeah that what I was thinking about but i was wondering if there was any faster way to get the trace instantly

Answer (score 0):

The `trace` command is usable only in debug mode and it display the text/value only in console...

> **trace(...parameters):void**
>
> Displays expressions, or writes to log files, while debugging. A single trace statement can support multiple arguments. If any argument in a trace statement includes a data type other than a String, the trace function invokes the associated toString() method for that data type. For example, if the argument is a Boolean value the trace function invokes Boolean.toString() and displays the return value.

If you need a different log system you can implement one...

ie.

You can create a class called Logger that takes a parameter and print to a label or directly to a file...